# Update one Table Using another Table Record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables as follows that joined by budget_id.

## finance_budget table

```
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| budget_id | amount |    date    | transfer_status | budget_status |
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|         1 | 135000 | 2019-10-01 | Pending         | issue         |
|         2 |  25000 | 2019-10-02 | Pending         | issue         |
|         3 | 234000 | 2019-10-03 | Pending         | issue         |
|         4 | 175000 | 2019-10-03 | Pending         | issue         |
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

## finance_budget_issue table

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| id | budget_id | office_id | amount | transfer_status | budget_status |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|  1 |         1 |       100 | 135000 | Pending         | issue         |
|  2 |         2 |       101 |  12500 | Pending         | issue         |
|  3 |         2 |       102 |  12500 | Pending         | issue         |
|  4 |         3 |       100 | 100000 | Pending         | issue         |
|  5 |         3 |       105 |  75000 | Pending         | issue         |
|  6 |         3 |       104 |  59000 | Pending         | issue         |
|  7 |         4 |       102 | 125000 | Pending         | issue         |
|  8 |         4 |       110 |  50000 | Pending         | issue         |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I tried to change the "**transfer_status**" of above two tables from "**Pending**" to "**Approved**" using my model

## Controller

```
public function approveIssues($id){
        $this->checkPermissions('index', 'pendingIssues');
        if(empty($id)){
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }

        if($this->Budget_model->approveIssues($id)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Allocation Approved successfully ..!!');
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error ...!!!');
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }
    }
```

## Model

```
function approveIssues($id)
    {

        $this->db->update('finance_budget_issue', array('transfer_status'=>'Approved'), array('id' => $id));
        $this->db->update('finance_budget', array('transfer_status'=>'Approved'), array('budget_id' => $id));

        if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {

            $activity=FZ_Controller::activity('approve','finance_budget_issues',$id,NULL);
            $this->db->insert('finance_user_activity',$activity);


            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I press the Approved button in my view the system shows "Error". If I remove the line,  **`$this->db->update('finance_budget', array('transfer_status'=>'Approved')`**, **`array('budget_id' => $id));`**
in my model the operation is executing successfully and shows the "**Allocation Approved successfully ..!!**" Message.

## Desired Output

I also need the transfer_status of finance_budget table should be into "Approved".

Comment: what is exact error you get?

Comment: @Ankur. I got the error of "$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error ...!!!');".

Comment: echo $str = $this->db->last_query();die; do it after update and check what is exact query it produce and run that query in your database.

Comment: May be you got idea about what is happen wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `Model` Code

```
function approveIssues($id) {

    $this->db->set('finance_budget.transfer_status','Approved');
    $this->db->set('finance_budget_issue.transfer_status','Approved');

    $this->db->where('finance_budget.budget_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('finance_budget_issue.id', $id);

    $this->db->update('finance_budget JOIN finance_budget_issue ON finance_budget.budget_id = finance_budget_issue.id');    

    if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {

        $activity=FZ_Controller::activity('approve','finance_budget_issues',$id,NULL);
        $this->db->insert('finance_user_activity',$activity);


        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

i think it's very helpful for you.

Comment: If I used, Following Error occurred. Error Number: 42000/1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id` SET `finance_budget`.`transfer_status` = 'Approved', `finance_budget_issue' at line 1

Comment: ohh.  will see it

Comment: Pls see my comment above